C# Xamarin dotnet Spire.pdf not reading arabic language
am using spire.pdf on xamarin platform, the goal is to export data as pdf, the the code that will add below is working perfectly but i faced a problem with arabic language.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Spire.Pdf;
using Spire.Pdf.Graphics;
using Spire.Pdf.Tables;
using System.Drawing;
using Spire.Pdf.ColorSpace;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;

namespace Test2
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<Car> cars;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            cars = new List<Car>()
            {
                new Car{ Name="مرسيدس",Model="E350",Color="Brown"},
                new Car{ Name="BMW",Model="i530",Color="Red"},
                new Car{ Name="Toyota",Model="Corolla",Color="White"},
                new Car{ Name="Hunda",Model="Civic",Color="Silver"},
                new Car{ Name="Toyota",Model="Carina",Color="Green"}
            };
        }

        private void btnPrint_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Create a PdfDocument object
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            //Add a page
            PdfPageBase page = doc.Pages.Add(PdfPageSize.A4, new PdfMargins(40));

            //Create a PdfTable object
            PdfTable table = new PdfTable();

            //Draw the text - alignment
            PdfTrueTypeFont font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("Arial", 12f,PdfFontStyle.Bold,true);
            PdfSolidBrush brush = new PdfSolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Blue);

            PdfStringFormat rightAlignment = new PdfStringFormat(PdfTextAlignment.Right, PdfVerticalAlignment.Middle);
            page.Canvas.DrawString("عبدالله للتجارة والمقاولات", font, brush, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width, 30, rightAlignment);
            page.Canvas.DrawString("نقليات-حفريات-مواد بناء", font, brush, page.Canvas.ClientSize.Width, 60, rightAlignment);


            //Set font for header and the rest cells
            table.Style.DefaultStyle.Font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("Arial", 12f, PdfFontStyle.Regular,true);
            table.Style.HeaderStyle.Font = new PdfTrueTypeFont("Arial", 12f, PdfFontStyle.Bold,true);

            //The data presented by list converted to datatable
            ListtoDataTableConverter converter = new ListtoDataTableConverter();
            DataTable dt = converter.ToDataTable(cars);

            //Set the datatable as the data source of table
            table.DataSource = dt;

            //Show header(the header is hidden by default)
            table.Style.ShowHeader = true;

            //Set font color and backgroud color of header row
            table.Style.HeaderStyle.BackgroundBrush = PdfBrushes.Gray;
            table.Style.HeaderStyle.TextBrush = PdfBrushes.White;

            //Set text alignment in header row
            table.Style.HeaderStyle.StringFormat = new PdfStringFormat(PdfTextAlignment.Center, PdfVerticalAlignment.Middle);

            //Set text alignment in other cells
            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                table.Columns[i].StringFormat = new PdfStringFormat(PdfTextAlignment.Center, PdfVerticalAlignment.Middle);
            }

            //Register with BeginRowLayout event
            table.BeginRowLayout += Table_BeginRowLayout;

            //Draw table on the page
            table.Draw(page, new PointF(0, 80));

            doc.SaveToFile("/storage/emulated/0/Download/2.pdf");
            DisplayAlert("Create PDF", "PDF has been created succcessfully", "OK");
        }

        //Event handler
        private static void Table_BeginRowLayout(object sender, BeginRowLayoutEventArgs args)
        {
            //Set row height
            args.MinimalHeight = 20f;

            //Alternate row color
            if (args.RowIndex < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (args.RowIndex % 2 == 1)
            {
                args.CellStyle.BackgroundBrush = PdfBrushes.LightGray;
            }
            else
            {
                args.CellStyle.BackgroundBrush = PdfBrushes.White;
            }
        }
    }
}


am testing the app on my physical phone samsumg galaxy m12.
i thought that the problem is related to the font type on my physical phone, so i tried to change the default but i didn't know how to do that because there are costanst or fixed fonts you can choose.

why there is no answers?
